# Sci fi or fantasy movie with 4 legged beasts buried in a huge ditch!

Tags: story-identification

Saw something on the Television last week.
Science fiction/famtasy movie or show (hope it wasn't a dream)...
I saw big bulldozers dumping huge 4 legged beasts into a massive ditch (to be buried).
Also saw a father show his son a unique plant in their yard, that had a cool little bug fly out of the flower. Seemed like the father was a soldier fighting these big 4 legged beasts. Beasts were elephant sized.

It was on HBO or Cinemax I think, not really sure.
   
Here is the other thing!! Not sure if it was the same movie, but one setting was mediaeval!
Two guys lured the demonic beast into a wooden fortress. There was a pool of oil created to try to get the beast into. Once the beast was in the pool, several men shot blazing arrows into the oil to burn the demonic beast. Just before the beast got into the fortress, it killed a priest with it's demonic/devilish tail.

What was I watching?? Was I dreaming this whole thing (hope not)??

Comment: Live action or cartoon? Played for laughs or straight? Hoe realistic were the beasts? Did it have, e.g. a Jurassic-parky feel? Any info is welcome.

Comment: Any idea on year of release? Was it B&W or in color? Did the yard and surrounding area look normal or apocalyptic? What station (aka where in the world did you see it)?

Comment: HBO, Cinemax possibly? Beasts were elephant sized.

Comment: USA. APOCALYPTIC FOR SURE. NOT ANIMATED.

Comment: Here is the other thing!! Not sure if it was the same movie, but one setting was mediaeval!!

Comment: Two guys lured the demonic beast into a wooden fortress. There was a pool created with oil. Once the beast was in, they shot blazing arrows into the oil to burn the demonic beast.

Comment: Before the beast got into the fortress, it killed a priest with it's demonic/devilish tail.

Comment: What channel was it on? Can you back-track their programme and see if you can find it? Also, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Don't know the channel

Comment: Can you edit the question and put all the info in, please. I'm now thinking dragons, can that be right? And the mediaeval setting vs the bulldozers, does this mean the story was spread out over several centuries, or was there time travel involved?

Comment: It was Outlander movie from 2008

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the 2008 movie ["Outlander"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlander_(film)), staring James Caviezel.
The film is a retelling of the Beowulf saga, involving elements of science fiction. Kainan (Beowulf) is a soldier from an interplanetary societey, that wiped out an alien life form called "Moorwen", to settle on their homeworld. To some circumstances he ends up crashing on earth during the iron ages, bringing with him the last surviving "Morween" (Grendel), and has to join a tribe of vikings in order to defeat the beast.

The bulldozer scene is from a flashback, when Kainan tells the story, how his people wiped out all the Moorwen on their planet, buried the bodies and created settlements.

The castle scene is happening before, where the vikings and Kainan are trying to lure the beast into a trap, after it killed the christian priest, who considered the beast some type of devil, that his faith would protect him from.